# Qual a função sintática de "suas canetas" na frase "Paulo deixou cair suas canetas."?

Tags: sintaxe, análise-sintática

Estou tendo problemas para analisar a função sintática de algumas frases envolvendo locuções verbais. Na frase:

**Paulo deixou cair suas canetas.**

"suas canetas" seria objeto direto?

Answer (score 4):

Ao que parece há mais do que uma análise possível. [Este artigo de 2007 no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/deixar--infinitivo/21934) apoia-se na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra para analisar “em moldes tradicionais” um frase do mesmo tipo: “Deixai vir a mim as criancinhas”. Aplicando essa análise à tua frase, *deixou cair* é uma perífrase verbal, com *deixar* como verbo auxiliar, e *suas canetas* é sim senhor o objeto direto da perífrase verbal.

Mas uma edição posterior da mesma gramática, de 2014, que eu tenho à minha frente, faz uma análise diferente. De acordo com esta análise, no teu exemplo não temos uma perífrase verbal, mas sim duas orações: *Paulo deixou* é a oração subordinante, e *cair suas canetas* uma oração subordinada, objeto direto de *deixou*, e *suas canetas* é o sujeito de *cair*, sendo equivalentes a duas frase seguintes:

> Paulo deixou **cair suas canetas**
> Paulo deixou **que caíssem suas canetas**

Cito a *Gramática* (Lisboa, 2014, p. 384):

> Se compararmos as duas frases:
>
> Mandei **que ele saísse**.
> Mandei-**o sair**.
>
> verificamos que o objeto direto, exigido pela forma verbal *mandei*, é expresso:
>
> *a*) na primeira, pela oração *que ele saísse;*
> *b*) na segunda, pelo pronome seguido do infinitivo: *o sair*. E verificamos também que o pronome *o* está para o infinitivo *sair* como o pronome *ele* para a forma finita *saísse*, da qual é sujeito. Logo, na frase acima o pronome *o* desempenha a função de sujeito do verbo *sair*.
>
> Construções semelhantes admitem os pronomes *me, te, nos, vos* (e o reflexivo *se*, que estudaremos à parte). Exemplos:
>
> Deixe-**me falar**.
> Mandam-**te entrar**
> Fez-**nos sentar**.

Repara que o sujeito do infinitivo ser um pronome não tem nada de especial (ou melhor, tem a curiosidade de termos um pronome oblíquo a servir de sujeito, mas isso é outra história). Para o que nos interessa aqui não há diferença qualitativa entre *deixe-me falar* e *deixe o Paulo falar* ou *deixe a caneta cair*.